# C# deep connected query

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Currently I have the below code which returns a list which goes through 4 tables Tournament -> Tournament_PlayerIDs -> PlayerIDs_Players -> Players.
What I am trying to do is return a list of tournaments in which a player has enrolled with one of their ID's to play in.

```
    public IEnumerable<Tournament> GetAllTournaments()
    {
        return _appDbContext.Tournaments
       .Include(f => f.PlayerIDIDs)
       .ThenInclude(PlayerIDIDs => PlayerIDIDs.Player)
       .ThenInclude(Player=> Player.Player)
       .Include(f => f.TournamentGame)
       .Include(f => f.TournamentFormat).ToList();
    }
```

What I would like is something like

```
public IEnumerable<Tournament> GetAllTournaments(string id)
    {
        return _appDbContext.Tournaments
       .Include(f => f.PlayerIDIDs)
       .ThenInclude(PlayerIDIDs => PlayerIDIDs.Player)
       .ThenInclude(Player=> Player.Player)
       .Include(f => f.TournamentGame)
       .Include(f => f.TournamentFormat)
       .Where (f.PlayerIDIDs.Player.Player.Id == id)
       .ToList();
    }
```

Model Structures

```
public class Tournament
{
    [Key]
    public int TournamentID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Game name is required")]
    public string TournamentName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5000, ErrorMessage = "Short Desc is required")]
    public string TournamentDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsMajorTournament { get; set; }
    public decimal TournamentFee { get; set; }
    public DateTime TournamentStartTime { get; set; }

    //Foregin Keys
    public int? GameID { get; set; }
    public Game TournamentGame { get; set; }
    public int? FormatID { get; set; }
    public Format TournamentFormat { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlayerID_Tournament> PlayerIDIDs { get; } = new List<PlayerID_Tournament>();

}

public class PlayerID_Tournament
{
    public int PlayerIDID { get; set; }
    public PlayerID Player { get; set; }
    public int TournamentID { get; set; }
    public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }
}

public class PlayerID
{
    //Identity for Player ID
    [Key]
    public int PlayerIDID { get; set; }
    //Id for Game such as DCI number
    public string PlayerGameID { get; set; }
    //game info
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public Game Game { get; set; }
    //user info
    public string PlayerId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Player { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlayerID_Tournament> Tournaments { get; } = new List<PlayerID_Tournament>();
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PlayerID> PlayerIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to have a where clause to filter the tournaments by the players player id(s).  It doesn't look like your method takes that info in either

Comment: I have not found a way to set a where clause to f.PlayerIDIDs.Player.Player.Id I updated the post to show that.

Comment: Need to know more about your entities to determine the type of query.  Some of your naming seems like the db structure is setup a little weird, for instance why does player have a player property?

Comment: Try `.Where(f => f.PlayerIDIDs.Any(pid =>pid.Player.Id == id))`

Comment: Updated with my data structures. Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: First, please fix the formatting; there is a big chunk of code in the middle that is not formatted. Second, just dumping a big pile of code and giving a list of things you want is not a *question*. Can you ask a *specific question* that will help get you unblocked?

Comment: @EricLippert I corrected the formatting. Someone asked for my models. They were not originally in the question which is clearly stated.

Comment: @just-my-name I think that is working. I will do a bit of testing real quick. Thank you again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is called [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___System_Func___0___1___2__). I believe the example in the link covers what you want (get all tournaments a given player participated)